# Redirect file to command, whose stdout is redirected to another command

Tags: bash, zsh

In a bash script, I want to redirect a file called `test` to `gzip -f`, then redirect STDOUT to `tar -xfzv`, and possibly STDERR to `echo` This is what I tried:

```
$ gzip -f <> ./test | tar -xfzv
```

Here, tar just complains that no file was given. How would I do what I'm attempting?

EDIT: the test file IS NOT a .tar.gz file, sorry about that
EDIT: I should be unzipping, then zipping, not like I had it written here

Comment: If the test is not a `.tar.gz`, it just doesn't make sense: you want to untar something that has not been tarred.

Comment: I know this makes no sense the way it's written here. Why I'm asking it is because I plan on making a PULL request to a server to get a gzipped file, which i want to unzip, encrypt with bcrypt, then make a tarball out of it again.

Comment: Okay, so to clarify it further: you want to get a `.gz` file, unzip it, encrypt it and then zip it back? In your last comment, you didn't say anything about tarball until the last step, and there's really no need to make a tarball out of a single file.

Comment: It's a directory of several files.

Comment: Edited the answer, please check if it answers your question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tar`'s `-f` switch tells it that it will be given a filename to read from. Use `-` for a filename to make `tar` read from stdout, or omit `-f` switch. Please read `man tar` for further information.

I'm not really sure about what you're trying to achieve in general, to be honest. The purpose of read-write redirection and `-f` `gzip` switch here is unclear. If the task is to unpack a `.tar.gz`, better use `tar xvzf ./test.tar.gz`.

As a side note, you cannot 'redirect stderr to echo', echo is just a built-in, and if we're talking about interactive terminal session, stderr will end up visible on your terminal anyway. You can redirect it to file with `2>$filename` construct.

EDIT: So for the clarified version of the question, if you want to decompress a gzipped file, run it through `bcrypt`, then compress it back, you may use something like

`gzip -dc $orig_file.tar.gz | bcrypt [your-switches-here] | gzip -c > $modified_file.tar.gz`

where `gzip`'s `-d` stands for decompression, and `-c` stands for 'output to stdout'.

If you want to encrypt each file individually instead of encrypting the whole tar archive, things get funnier because `tar` won't read input from stdin. So you'll need to extract your files somewhere, encrypt them and then tgz them back. This is not the shortest way to do that, but in general it works like this:

```
mkdir tmp ; cd tmp
tar xzf ../$orig_file.tar.gz
bcrypt [your-switches-here] *
tar czf ../$modified_file.tar.gz *
```

Please note that I'm not familiar with `bcrypt` switches and workflow at all.